# Change mediaelement Source Based on Actions

Tags: wpf, vb.net, video, mediaelement

I have a WPF 4 and VB.net 2010 project. I am playing videos in a single mediaelement. This is what I need to do:

When the window first opens, I have the first video play just fine. However, it is after this video plays that I run into trouble figuring out how to do the following.

1. I need the video source to change immediately following a single play through of any video, and I need this video (henceforth referred to as an "ambient" video) to loop forever.
2. When a certain event happens, I need to change the video source again, have it play once through, and then go back to looping ambient video in step 1.

Here is the rub, however. Many of the video triggers are inside of If-Then or Select Case statements in code behind, so I'm not exclusively using simple WPF events such as "MouseUp" or "MouseEnter".

Also, all videos must play in the same mediaelement, for performance reasons.

Thank you in advance!

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.source%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) of the media element is a DependencyProperty, as such any changes to it will be immediately reflected in the UI.

If you combine this with the [MediaEnded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.mediaended%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) event that is fired, you can set the Source and your problem is solved.

When you hit the triggers in code, you can either call a method or fire an event.  You will have to use some semblance of a [State Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternState.aspx) to deal with the other logic.  As an aside, check out [Programming Without Ifs](http://programmingwithoutifs.blogspot.com/), it's an awesome intro on how to avoid insane conditional logic.

Comment: For some reason, firing the source change from MediaEnded does not work. What does the UnloadedBehavior of the mediaelement have to be set to?

Comment: What do you mean "firing the source change"?  When the MediaEnded event fires, just set the source to the new source.  You may need to do this with a delegate.

Comment: That's what I mean...I tried just that. In the MediaElement event, I put the code to change the source, but that code is never fired when the event fires (I'm suspecting that the event itself isn't being fired, tho). So, that again brings me back to the question: in order for that mediaended event to work, what does the unloadedbehavior on the WPF mediaelement need to be set to?

Comment: Hmm...can you try MarkerReached? And set a Marker at the end of the clip? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.markerreached(v=VS.95).aspx#Y500

Comment: Found the problem. See my answer below. Since you were originally going down the right path, and I hate accepting my own answers, you get the bounty. TY!

Comment: Glad to hear it.  No problem if you decide to accept your own answers, most of the time I do the same since I need to fix it faster than SO can come up with the answer for it.

Answer (score 0):

I set the mediaelement's LoadedBehavior to "Play" and Unloadedbehavior to "Stop", then I was able to just change the source of the mediaelement itself in code, and put the video I needed played after every video into the MediaEnded event.

It turns out that MediaEnded does not fire automatically when the LoadedBehavior is set to "Manual", unless "Stop" is explicitly called in code.

I hate accepting my own answers, so Nate Noonen gets the bounty (he was going down the right alley originally)! TY!